# how to call an api method updated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i trying to utilise the channel advisor api but i stuck due to my lack of knowledge of c# and apis.

i need to perform the RequestAccess operation in this api link https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v7/AdminService.asmx?WSDL

i'm stuck at where to start, i have created a service reference in visual studio and here is my code so far, any help would be great

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int accountID = 132;
        channeladvisor.AdminService CallWebService = new channeladvisor.AdminService();
        channeladvisor.APIResultOfBoolean sGetValue = CallWebService.RequestAccess(accountID);

        MessageBox.Show(ToString(sGetValue));

    }
```

I have updated my code above but am still lost in terms of how do i actually get the result of the api call or check if it has even worked

Comment: So tell us what's going wrong

Comment: i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred when i click the button

Comment: If you look at the WSDL it expects an integer when Calling the RequestAccess function and won't return a string but an APIResultOfBoolean.

Comment: thanks @JaggenSWE how would i pass the integer and how would i get the APIResultOfBoolean

Comment: Something along the lines of ServiceReference1.APIResultOfBoolean sGetValue = CallWebService.RequestAccess(i), where i is your integer. I have no idea what these values are or how the API is set up, but that's the syntax of things atleast.

Comment: @JaggenSWE thank you, i will give it a go

Comment: Best of luck, it's not all that hard. :)